# Feature is a point or polygon

Tags: polygon, vector, point, feature-class

Im new to GIS and am just curious if there is an instance where a feature can be a point in one map and a polygon in another map and vice versa?

Comment: Welcome to GIS and welcome to SE!  Is this a homework question because a quick trawl of publicly available data will give you the answer and a brief glance at a basic GIS textbook will tell you why?  If you have a specific issue in mind, please edit your question.

Comment: Its not a homework question but I am just curious. I just started learning about GIS through a ArcGIS textbook trial I received but am unable to find the answer I am looking for.

Comment: It's an interesting question, although I'm not quite sure where you're coming from. Have you gotten to the place in the textbook where it teaches you how to create features? Verify that you can create both points and polygons. Is there anything to prevent you from creating a point to represent a spatially extensive feature or from creating a polygon to represent a point-like feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a great question and one with more relevance as we start using different technologies to store spatial data such as PostGIS.

There are two issues involved here, from what I can think about:

1) **Scale**: I used to teach cartography students that a City from the view of "The Country" is a point, but as you zoom in to the scale of a "region", the City has a boundary that is a polygon, which leads to:

2) **Geometry**: You can store a City as a polygon, and you can 'geoprocess' it with ArcGIS into a point (a new dataset) for viewing at smaller scales (zoomed out). PostGIS, as I mentioned, gives the unique ability to create process this data on the fly using spatial functions in the database. Cartographically speaking, your map would call 1 layer of the original polygons at large scales (zoomed in) then call a 'view' of those polygons that converts the polygons to points on the fly (I'm thinking specifically of the ST_AsPoint function).